# A coding problem: the least possible object group

Tags: c#, algorithm

I came up with a coding problem which I can just think of brute forcing all the combination to find the answer. Are there any better method other then brute force?

The problem is as following:

Within an IDictionary object,
`IDictionary<int,List<object>>`
find the least possible group of objects
where each index can have only a finite number of groups.

Lets say the index of IDictionary is the id of a person, 
each person can have a list of objects, each objects consist of two parameters:

`int weight`

`String origin`

If 2 person having a sublist of objects that is identical,

identical set of objects can be grouped. Find the least possible number of groups in the IDictionary.

e.g

Person1: Object(1,"Korea"),Object(2,"German"),Object(3,"Japan")

Person2: Object(1,"Korea"),Object(2,"German")

Output:

```
    The least possible group is 2

    Group1: Object(1,"Korea"),Object(2,"German")

    Group2: Object(3,"Japan")

    Person1:Group1,Group2

    Person2:Group1

    or

    Group1: Object(1,"Korea"),Object(2,"German"),Object(3,"Japan")

    Group2: Object(1,"Korea"),Object(2,"German")

    Person1:Group1

    Person2:Group2
```

If the maximum group is set to 1 then only the second answer is accepted.

The function should have 2 parameters:

`int maximumGroup`

`IDictionary<int,List<object>>`

Comment: We know ***your*** assignment. What did ***you*** try to achieve it and what is ***our*** job here?

Comment: Try following : var results = dict.OrderBy(x => x.Value.Count).GroupBy(x => x.Value.Count).FirstOrDefault();